# Is Castle Windsor able to resolve contravariant generics?

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

So, the problem:

```
interface IControl<in T> where T : Base
{
    void Execute(T item);
}


class ControlDerived : IControl<Derived>
{
    public void Execute(Derived item)
    {
    }
}

class ControlBase : IControl<Base>
{
    public void Execute(Base item)
    {
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
}
```

Is it possible to make Windsor work like this:

```
var ctls = container.ResolveAll<IControl<Derived>>()
ctls.Lenght == 2 ?
```

So I could get both implementations?

Comment: If you're using the latest version and .NET 4 build I think it should work. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lazy :p

I ran the following test and it passes

```
[Test]
public void ResolveAll_can_resolve_contravariant_components()
{
 Container.Register(Component.For<IAmContravariant<Base>>().ImplementedBy<ContravariantBase>(),
              Component.For<IAmContravariant<Derived>>().ImplementedBy<ContravariantDerived>());

 var all= Container.ResolveAll<IAmContravariant<Derived>>();
 Assert.AreEqual(2, all.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have some misconfiguration.